# How close can I make different monster spawners to be able to work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a monster farm and I’m worndering if there is a certain distance needed between spawners

Answer (score 1):

Mob [spawners](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawner) activate when within 16 blocks (sphere) from the player. Any number of them within that range will work, with the obvious caveat that the spawner itself is not a spawnable space - the mobs need empty volume to spawn. The more spawners you put within the 9x9x3 volume centered on a spawner, the less empty space for mobs to spawn within the volume you have left.

But finding more than two spawners within 31 blocks from each other (so there's a location between them where the player activates both) is quite rare, so it's not a big worry.

[image]

On the other hand, if you plan a general mob farm, you'll be better off with a natural spawning based mob grinder than the spawners. Spawners only spawn up to 4 mobs every 25 seconds on the average (between 10s and 40s random cooldown) and only of the type the spawner is, while a good general mob farm will spawn all, or at least most kinds of mobs and its speed is limited only by your ability to kill them fast enough to keep the number below mob cap.

Comment: Yeah, but a spawner farm is a lot easier to build than a generald overworld farm for mutiple reasons, one, because of mobcap you would need to build the farm 128 blocks(or at least the afk position of the farm) in the air. The downside to this is that you would have to build a wayy larger platform for them to spawn in to combat the fact that they dont spawn as quickly in higher altitudes. Also, when other people are in the dimension and have mobs in caves, the mobcap is taken up and the farm is slowed down dramatically. Spawner farms, while slow, don't have to deal with any of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki, it says "A spawner activates when a player comes within a spherical radius of 16 blocks from the center point of the block; i.e. 15.5 blocks from the block itself."Which means that you have to be 15.5 or fewer blocks away from the spawner in order to for the spawner to activate and spawn mobs.

Answer (score -1):

It will spawn mobs if the player is within a 8*8*3 radius of each spawner

Comment: 9x9x3 is the volume where mobs spawn, centered on the spawner. The spawner activates way before entering that volume.